# C++ How to change the output on a new array

Tags: c++, arrays, perfect-square

So I wrote a program that is supposed select the perfect squares from an array and put it into another array. Example: (2,4,13,5,25,66) and the second array(the result) should look like this (4,25)
My result looks like this (0,4,0,0,25,0) ...so its half good ...how to make it show only 4,25 ?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<math.h.>

int main()
{
    int A[100],i,n,p,j;

    cout << "Number of array elements=";
    cin >> n;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"A["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>A[i];
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        p=sqrt(A[i]) ;   
        if(p*p==A[i])
            A[j]=A[i];
        else
            A[i]=0;

        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

USING ONLY c++ basic commands...as i did

Comment: What do you think `j` will do? And is there some reason "another array" is the same array?

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a separate count of how many perfect squares you've found and use that to place your answers into an array of perfect squares:

```
int squares[???];
// ...
if(p*p==A[i]) {
  squares[squaresFound]=A[i];
  squaresFound++;
}
```

The problem now will be to decide how long the `squares` array should be. You don't know ahead of time how many squares you're going to get. Are you going to have it the same size as `A` and fill the rest with `0`s? Or do you want the array of squares to be exactly the right size?

If you want it to be the right size, you're much better off using a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> squares;
// ...
if(p*p==A[i]) {
  squares.push_back(A[i]);
}
```

But I think your silly "only basic C++ commands" restriction will not allow you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You talk about a second array (the result), yet your code declares only one array! Additionally, you reference `A[j]`, but your `j` has not be initialized.

You should declare another array `B[100]`, initialize `j` to zero, and then use this code when you find a square:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i=0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    int p = sqrt(A[i]);
    if(p*p==A[i]) {
        B[j++] = A[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is technically possible to use `A` as the result array as long as `j` is actually used.

Comment: @EmilVikström Absolutely! However, this is not the way the question is phrased. I strongly suspect that this is either a school assignment or a self-study where the second array is required.

Answer (score 0):

Make another array, remove all occurrences of 0 from the resultArray and add non-0 to newArray.

OR

```
int j=0
if(A[i]==p*p) 
  squares[j++]=A[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int A[100];
    int n;

    cout << "Number of array elements = " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "A[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    int B[100];
    int cnt_sqr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int p = sqrt(A[i]);
        if (p * p == A[i])
        {
            B[cnt_sqr++] = A[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt_sqr; i++)
    {
        cout << B[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Full code of that about what you were told above

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify your code you can write the following:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    p=sqrt(A[i]) ;   
    if(p*p==A[i])
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

It will print you only perfect squares.

If you want to copy elements to another array:

```
int squares[100] = {0}; // Assuming that all values can be perfect squares
int square_count = 0;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    p=sqrt(A[i]) ;   
    if(p*p==A[i])
    {
        squares[square_count++] = A[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah tnx very usefull answer but i have to make a new vector that will show those values